# Contacts Sections Disappear

Tags: contacts

I have a strange issue after upgrading to CiviCRM 5.39.0 in our production environment.  We did not have this problem in development.  There are two manifestations of what looks like some kind of template issue.

1. When editing a contact I cannot see the *Communication Preferences.* On the view page I can see and edit the *Communication Preferences* just fine.

[image]
[image]

2. For custom field sets I can see them on the Contact view page.  I can edit the fields in the section with the click and edit. When I save after editing the fields the little triangle and the field set name still shows but the fields no longer show.

[image]

If I refresh the page then it goes back to normal.

I have cleared the cache, checked all the paths, checked that I have the same problem when the backend theme is set to none.  I should also note there are no JS errors on the console.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you add a few screenshots?

Comment: @Aidan, I have added screenshots.  Also, I added that there are no JS issues on the console.  Thanks!

Comment: Not that it helps you much, but I've checked one of my 5.39.0 systems and Communication Preferences shows normally in contact edit.